# Update mulitple values of a single column in an SQLite DB using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, random, sql-update

I am accessing a SQLite DB (3.7.11) using Python:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
```

To insert/add a single row I can use e.g.:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO random_points (value) VALUES ("42")")
```

My table has already 100 rows and instead of adding a row I would
like to update the entire value-column with random numbers from
a Gaussian distribution with mu=0 and sigma=1:

```
import random
random_numbers = [random.gauss(0,1) for x in range(0,100)]
```

How can I use these random numbers an fill them into the value column
of my Sqlite database?

Comment: Do you really need to update? Can't you throw away the old rows and insert new ones?

Comment: I can't throw away the old rows as the table also contains some other columns besides the value-col.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one column you can use a `for` loop :

```
random_numbers = [random.gauss(0,1) for x in range(0,100)]
for number in random_numbers :
    cur.execute("UPDATE word SET column_name=? WHERE your_condition ",(number))
```